# Why am I getting this error in pystyle for the fade animation... how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, ascii, helper

```
import time
from pystyle import Colorate, Colors, Anime, Center


def main():
    banner = '''

▒███████▒ ▒█████   ███▄ ▄███▓ ▄▄▄▄    ██▓▓█████ 
▒ ▒ ▒ ▄▀░▒██▒  ██▒▓██▒▀█▀ ██▒▓█████▄ ▓██▒▓█   ▀ 
░ ▒ ▄▀▒░ ▒██░  ██▒▓██    ▓██░▒██▒ ▄██▒██▒▒███   
  ▄▀▒   ░▒██   ██░▒██    ▒██ ▒██░█▀  ░██░▒▓█  ▄ 
▒███████▒░ ████▓▒░▒██▒   ░██▒░▓█  ▀█▓░██░░▒████▒
░▒▒ ▓░▒░▒░ ▒░▒░▒░ ░ ▒░   ░  ░░▒▓███▀▒░▓  ░░ ▒░ ░
░░▒ ▒ ░ ▒  ░ ▒ ▒░ ░  ░      ░▒░▒   ░  ▒ ░ ░ ░  ░
░ ░ ░ ░ ░░ ░ ░ ▒  ░      ░    ░    ░  ▒ ░   ░   
  ░ ░        ░ ░         ░    ░       ░     ░  ░
░                                  ░            

    '''
    print(Anime.Fade(mode=1,
        text=banner,
        color=Colors.green_to_yellow))

    time.sleep(10)

main()



#output
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Not7e\Desktop\main.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Not7e\Desktop\main.py", line 34, in main
    print(Anime.Fade(mode=1,
  File "C:\Users\Not7e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystyle\__init__.py", line 561, in Fade
    Anime._anime(text, color, mode, interval)
  File "C:\Users\Not7e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pystyle\__init__.py", line 667, in _anime
    _stdout.write(mode(color, text))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

"""
```

I'm having an issue with the pystyle Anime.fade Function. It says that the mode can have "any" I've tried an Int, string, List & etc... and still no luck I've been trying to fix this for the  past hour if anyone knows how to fix this please show me :( or tell me what I am doing wrong I did the same exact thing before and it worked Idk what's going on now. It's supposed to have a color fading effect on the banner with the colors green and yellow.

Comment: I'm guessing the `mode=1` is causing this. Try to pass `mode = Colorate.Vertical` as an argument.